# How to use multiple threads for multiple file reading/writing operations in C?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, file-handling

I'm trying to analyse the optimum number of threads required to perform a large file reading/writing operation on multiple files.
So how do I proceed with creating multiple threads and assigning each thread with some number of files to speed up the execution time?
Language used- C

Comment: Hi Ravsehaj, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP for creating threads and managing them efficiently for your analysis.

In you case what you would be doing is using multiple single threads and assigning the workload to them or a team of threads which will recieve equal share of work. Examples below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // split work in sections
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {    
        #pragma omp section
        {
            function_1(); // where you perform R/W operations
        }

        #pragma omp section
        {
            function_2(); // where you perform R/W operations or other
        }
    }

    // split work on N threads equally
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        // where you perform R/W operations
    }
    int threadNum = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Number of threads used: %d\n",threadNum);

    /*
    example for loop: if you have 2 threads this work would be split with
    i that runs from 0 to 49999 while the second gets a version running from 50000 to 99999.
    */
    int arr[100000];
    #pragma omp parallel for  
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
          arr[i] = 2 * i;
        }
    }
    int threadNum = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Number of threads used: %d\n",threadNum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: specific code from the link would have been more beneficial to the questioner